# Operator overloading compiles in Visual Studio 2013 but not gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-2013

I have a class where I am overloading the << and + operators like this:

```
    friend MyObject operator+(MyObject lhs, MyObject rhs){
        MyObject obj;
        obj.Property = lhs.Property + rhs.Property;
        return obj;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, MyObject& n) {
        os << MyObject.Property;      //property is a double
        return os;
    }
```

This compiles in both Visual Studio and gnu++98 with no problems.  I can also call them like this without any problems:

```
MyObject obj1, obj2;
obj1.PutInValidState();
cout << obj1;
obj1 = obj1 + obj2;
```

However, when I call them at the same time like this:

```
cout << obj1 + obj2;
```

Visual Studio will compile it (and gives the correct output), but gnu++98 gives me the error "no match for 'operator<<' in '
   std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream&, const char*)".  I can get it to compile in both by adding const to the parameter in the function definition like this:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyObject& n) {
```

What is going on here?  Why do I need the const to make it work in gnu++98 but not in Visual Studio?

Comment: Turn on your warnings in Visual Studio.  G++ is actually correct here, and VS will tell you if you pay attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cout << obj1 + obj2;
```

is syntax sugar for

```
operator<<(cout, operator+(obj1,obj2));
```

here you can see that the `n` parameter in your operator<<() overload is being bound to the value being returned by operator+(), which is a temporary object. Now, in C++, there's a rule that non-const reference parameters can **not** bind to temporaries, which is why it won't compile in gcc.

Visual studio, on the other hand, has a language extension which allows non-const reference parameters to bind to temporaries. I wish it didn't, since that extension is one of the ones that has bitten me when porting code to other compilers.

Comment: VS2013 has a flag that disbles this.

Comment: @Yakk ...which should be set by default, but isn't. Having to instruct tools to *not* do *non*-standard actions is... irritating.